# homestead PATH not working (Laravel, PHP)

Tags: php, laravel, path, vagrant, homestead

I am trying to get a Vagrant/Homestead/Laravel up and running to do some PHP projects. I follow the instructions in the video:

https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/2

But whenever I reach the point where he tests the **'homestead'** command on the terminal (currently I am using ZSH), I get:

`zsh: command not found: homestead`

I do not know where my **.bash_profile** should go. I typed the following commands in the terminal (in order):

```
cd  
touch ~/.bash_profile  
nano .bash_profile
```

and it shows me an empty file (it did not exist before since I just formatted my MacBook). I wrote the following and saved the file:

`PATH=/Users/Jack/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH`

And then I try to execute the command **homestead** in the terminal, but it still doesn't work...

Why is it not working? Also, should I put the .bash_profile in my **cd** (root directory) as a User or as a root user (**sudo su**).

Any help/advice is greatly appreciated!

Cheers!

UPDATE:

My .zshrc file:

```
# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH=/Users/Jack/.oh-my-zsh
export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"

# Set name of the theme to load.
# Look in ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/

....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are using `zsh` so you will want to add composer to your $PATH defined in your `.zshrc` file.  Your `.zshrc` file should be located in your home directory. Your home directory is referenced by `~`.  Your `.zshrc` file should be located in `~/.zshrc`

Next, add composer to your path. Open your `.zshrc` file with  nano and update:

```
# User configuration

export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
```

To:

```
# User configuration

export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
```

Now reload  zsh  with

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

NOTE:  If `~` doesn't work, try `$HOME`.

Comment: I tried it but it does not work. It still shows `zsh: command not found: homestead`. Refer to my update to see my .zshrc content.

Comment: In your terminal, `echo $PATH` and post the result

Comment: So composer isn't there. Did you run `source ~/.zshrc`?

Comment: hmmm... yes I did... so how could I fix this?

Comment: # Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH=/Users/Jack/.oh-my-zsh
PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"

I removed it but whenever I run the command `homestead` it still does not recognize the command. The output of `echo $PATH` is still the same. One question: Do I have to do this in the machine ABSOLUTE PATH or is executing all these commands from my regular path aka 'Users/Jack' is OK? Thanks!

Comment: By ABSOLUTE PATH I mean running `sudo su` and a `cd` after

Comment: Your home directory is fine. Did you source ~/.zshrc?

Comment: Try replacing ~ with $HOME

Comment: PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH" and still no results (after sourcing and closing terminal)

Comment: Is PATH being set anywhere else in that file?

Comment: indeed... I moved everything to user config in the .zshrc file.. and now a different $PATH is being echoed -> `/Users/Jack/.composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` but the homestead command doesnt work still

Comment: Is `composer` installed globally on your machine?  I.e., if you type `composer` from any directory, what happens?

Comment: I installed homestead by cloning the repository from GitHub... does this make any difference? Also, if I go to my Homestead folder, I see the homestead UNIX file. But whenever I try to run it, even in that directory, it does not recognize the command, is this normal?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83650/discussion-between-raphael-rafatpanah-and-jack-gal).